# WPF: TextTrimming in CheckBox with no fixed width

Tags: wpf, checkbox, grid, resizable, texttrimming

I have a checkbox located in a grid with a column span of 3, where 2 of the columns are resizable, and can be resized during runtime.

I want the checkbox to show ellipsis when its text doesn't fit, but can't get this to work.

Here is my XAML code.

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
    <CheckBox IsEnabled="False"  Grid.Row="2" Padding="5" Margin="11,12,0,0" Name="chkSelectedCat" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
         <AccessText Text="Search in selected category only." TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    </CheckBox>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

The `CheckBox` in question is located within a `Grid`, which is in turn contained within a `GroupBox`, which is in a column adjacent to a column which is resized using a `GridSplitter`.

Comment: How do you resize your columns, and which column resize does not work ? I put a GridSplitter in the third column and resize with ellipsis works as intended.

Comment: @Sisyphe The grid is located within a GroupBox, which is in turn located within a resizable column. This (outer) column can be resized by the user using a GridSplitter located in the column to its left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `GroupBox` allots infinite width to its child controls, as discussed at this [MSDN forum thread.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/9ee21e9e-120c-4239-a0c8-79dc98c3fee9)

In fact, when setting a `MaxWidth` to the `CheckBox`, text trimming worked and the ellipsis were displayed.

However the `CheckBox` maximum width needed to be changed during runtime.

I tried using a [MultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to bind the `MaxWidth` of the `CheckBox` to the total `ActualWidth` of the three columns, but the `Convert` method was only being called during initialisation (again I think this is something to do with how the `GroupBox` assigns sizes to its child controls).

Anyway I managed to achieve what I wanted by removing the `ChechkBox`'s `AccessText` and using a `TextBlock` in a `StackPanel` in its stead, and then surrounding everything with a `Border`.

```
<Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="chkBorder" SizeChanged="chkBorder_SizeChanged">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
               <CheckBox IsEnabled="False" Padding="0" Margin="11,7,0,5" Name="chkSelectedCat"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
               <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Name="txtChkSelectedCat" Text="Search in selected category only." TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,5,5"/>
      </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

When the size of the `Border` is changed, I update the `Width` of the StackPanel in the event handler, and the text in the `TextBox` trims accordingly.

```
private void chkBorder_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
     this.txtChkSelectedCat.Width = this.chkBorder.ActualWidth - this.chkSelectedCat.ActualWidth - 11 - 5 - 5; // margins
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future (even though it is sort of a hack).

**UPDATE**

If you can eliminate the `StackPanel` and use a `Grid` instead, `TextTrimming` works automatically, without having to do any event handling, as shown below.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsEnabled="False" Padding="0" Margin="11,7,0,5" Name="chkSelectedCat" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Black"  Name="txtChkSelectedCat" Text="Search in selected category only." TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,5,5" MouseLeftButtonDown="txtChkSelectedCat_MouseLeftButtonDown" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=chkSelectedCat, Path=ToolTip}" />
</Grid>
```

Make sure to set the `Width` of the column containing the textbox to `"*"`, because `"Auto"` basically tells the `TextBox` that it can have as much space as it wants, so `TextTrimming` would not work.